# 1050p Retina VS 1080p FHD Monitor

Tags: macos, mac, display, video, resolution

Good morning my friends, I hope everyone is doing well. I need a straight forward answer in layman terms on resolution scaling. 1080p vs 1050p M1 13 inch MacBook. I know that our 13 inch Macs are 1600p but scaling closest to that is 1050p. 1080p Is clearly a higher number but we have a 1600p display selected at 1050p. So when playing games will 1050p look much better than 1080p? if so how and why. as a side note 800p is 1600p cut in half so I know thats the cleanest option so wouldn't that be even better then 1050p? ive searched for 100's of hours fellas I just want answers please.

Answer (score 1):

The 13" M1 MacBook Pro/Air has an actual display of 2560 x 1600 pixels.

The scaled resolutions offered are 1680 by 1050 (x1.52), 1440 by 900 (x1.77), and 1024 by 640 (x2.5) pixels.

The scale factors in brackets show the number of real pixels that make a scaled cell. It is perhaps curious that there isn't a 1280 x 800 (x2) size.

A size of 1728 x 1080 (x1.48) might also be possible, though there may be *maths reasons* why calculating these missing scalings is difficult.

My advice is simply to test each of the available sizes and see what quality and speed you get. There are programs that allow custom screen scalings: [SwitchResX](https://www.madrau.com) is the best known.

Comment: RDM - https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM - is also a good app to easily checkout many different screen resolutions.